# Windows+IntelliJ IDEA 2021.3.1+Git for Windows v2.34.1: Git bash shell in Idea terminal, skip to next/previous word not working ( Ctrl + ← | Ctrl+ → )

Tags: windows, terminal, shell, intellij-idea, git-for-windows

I installed git for windows and linked bash shell in IntelliJ but I'm missing one shortcut which saves me a lot of time is a direct move to the next/previous word in the command line. how can I make this work?
It works when I use the shell directly.

[image]

Comment: I don't see this problem at all.  Not sure what problem you are having.  I set my terminal to "C:\Program Files\Git\bin\bash.exe" from the default of cmd.exe.  It works like a champ to include skipping words with `[Ctrl]` + `[->]` and `[Ctrl]` + `[<-]`.  BTW, your title is misleading as `>` and `<` aren't arrow keys and might confuse readers that you are trying to use GT and LT keys (you aren't.. right?).

Comment: update the title, but it's not working for me